# How to remove dead region server from EMR hbase cluster?

Tags: hbase, amazon-emr

I have created Hbase application in EMR cluster with Master and Core nodes 1 and 2 respectively. Hbase was configured S3 storage mode for storage. I deleted one Core node out of 2 for checking HA. After EMR spawned new core node.

It is showing exception as **'ERROR: No route to host'** when i execute a query because deleted dead region server is not cleared, still some region are using deleted region server.

**How to clear dead region server automatically if enabled Auto scaling for Core Node?**

Comment: I ran into the same issue, my use case is that I have a mapreduce job that scans certain table on an EMR cluster. The data is stored on S3 and EMRFS is enabled to ensure consistency, the mapreduce job would randomly fail with the "No route to host" error above. The HBase UI shows some dead regions servers which are from previous EMR job that uses the same data on S3. Any update on this?